# self referencing table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table like this,

```
  table name = staff
  staff-id(pk), last-name, first-name, job-title, reports-to(fk)
```

Reports to is a self referencing key.

I already have data to insert in to this table. In my data all the staff members have reports-to person but MD does not have a reports-to person as MD is the highest position. So as it references to no key how can I create table as a self referencing foreign key because insertion will probably cause a problem.

Data to MD column is

staff-id last-name  first-name job-title reports-to

200       Vellum     Harry      MD         0

```
   CREATE TABLE staff
    ( staff-id number not null,
     last-name varchar2(20) not null,
     first-name varchar2(20),
     job-title varchar2(20) not null,
     reports-to number not null,
     CONSTRAINT staffid_pk PRIMARY KEY (staff-id)
     CONSTRAINT reportsto_fk FOREIGN KEY (staff-id) REFERENCES staff(staff-id)
     );
```

Can I have MD's reports-to key as his primary key, if so again adding will cause a problem.
How to solve this problem?
I'm using oracle 11g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make MD report to self (i.e. set `Reports-To` column to `staff-id` column value) or make `Reports-To` column nullable (Foreign key columns can be equal to `NULL`)

Comment: Or add a "nobody" record to the `staff` table with a `staff_id` value of 0 or -1 or something like that.

Comment: @David Faber: I tend to stay away from 'special' values if I can (with NULL being a special value, granted, but with a universal meaning). Less surprises down the chain....

Comment: I'm not particular big on the technique I mentioned either, just thought I would throw it out there.